# angularjs if else statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<ng-switch on="MyData.Status">
    <p ng-switch-when="2">
        <p ng-if="MyData.SomeProp == false">
            Message 1
        </p>
        <p ng-if="MyData.SomeProp == true">
            Message 2
        </p>
    </p>
</ng-switch>
```

I want to execute `MyData.SomeProp == false` block of code only when ng-switch-when="2.

pseudo code would be

```
if (MyData.Status == 2){
   if (MyData.SomeProp == false){
      print message 1
   } 
   else{
      print message 2
   }
}
```

how to do this simple statement using angularjs

Comment: are you using php also?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) instead of `ng-if`:

```
<ng-switch on="MyData.Status">
    <p ng-switch-when="2">
        <p ng-show="MyData.SomeProp == false">
            Message 1
        </p>
        <p ng-show="MyData.SomeProp == true">
            Message 2
        </p>
    </p>
</ng-switch>
```

Comment: Although you could do it without the ==true and ==false bits.

Comment: @Stu I think `== true` is required, if the value of `SomeProp` is `truefalse`, anything other than `true` or `false`. We don't know it yet, better to go safer side